# Problem with light switch

Tags: electrical

I have a situation where power comes to a switch and the light either won't go on at all or else it stays on continuously. What can be wrong?

Comment: Are you messing with the wiring, or did the switch just start malfunctioning?

Comment: It was wired by someone else incorrectly and I am trying to get it to work to be able to properly switch it on and off.

Comment: So you're messing with the wiring. Can you describe the wiring? How many cables enter the box? How many and what color are all the wires, and how are they connected (a diagram would be helpful)? What have you tried already? Are there any other switches involved (multi-way switch)?

Comment: Total of 1 dimmer and 2 switches in the box. The dimmer and the other switch work fine. The last switch has 3 wires (blk, wht, and red) only need 2 wires for the switch. I also have another 2 wires (blk, wht) and nopower goes to the 2 wires. I have power going to the switch but it won't turn the light on. Another problem, the dimmer is heating up the screws.

Comment: If I had to guess, those other two wires are the switch leg and the neutral, except then it wouldn't work at all. What causes it to be intermittent? : Toggling either of the two other switches?

Comment: You should post some photos. Three wires attached to a switch usually means it's a 3-way, or a smart switch.   How was it originally wired, and what were the symptoms that made you suspect a problem?

Comment: @Tester101 The symptoms that made me suspect there was a problem was that I had to turn off the dimmer switch for it to work.